# Exact number of characters with leading spaces

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to figure out how to match the following rules...

- Exactly 4 characters (alphanumeric) or zero characters
- Characters can spaces if only used to pad on left
- Can NOT contain just 4 spaces

**Example of acceptable matches:**

```
""
"  43"
" D42"
```

**Example of NON-acceptable matches:**

```
"1 A3"
"1   "
"    "
"A 1 "
```

I have tried using the following regex but it just does not give the expected results.

```
(([\s]*[0-9A-Z]*){4}|)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be trivially easy with a simple loop rather than using regex?

Comment: Try [`^(?!.{5}| +$) *[a-zA-Z0-9]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/LBv1rY/1)

Comment: @JonathanWood hehe that's what I was thinking but I have been trying my best to use regex to learn it.  I know it's powerful and I want to be good with it but I usually take the easy way (not knowing it well) out and use code to try and accomplish my task. ;)

Comment: So when padded to the left with spaces, the overall length is still restricted to 4? So `"    1234"` would not be acceptable?

Comment: Correct @MattBurland.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I couldn't get that to work, I tried to edit a few things to make it work but it just would not do it.  Also, only allow CAPS (no a-z) and it's in the middle of a line (not the entire line).  ;)

Comment: Perhaps, what you need is the regex by dasblinkenlight without anchors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex is not very good about counting, but when the number is low, such as four, you can build a simple repetitive regex that does the job:

```
^(|[0-9A-Z]{4}| {1}[0-9A-Z]{3}| {2}[0-9A-Z]{2}| {3}[0-9A-Z]{1})$
```

This regex lists an empty string, along with four acceptable usages of space:

- No space, four characters
- One space, three characters
- Two spaces, two characters
- Three spaces, one character

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/RYz3Bd/1)

Comment: It's arguable, but some people may find it easier to read with explicit quantifiers for the spaces: `^(|[0-9A-Z]{4}| [0-9A-Z]{3}| {2}[0-9A-Z]{2}| {3}[0-9A-Z])$` or even `^(|[0-9A-Z]{4}| {1}[0-9A-Z]{3}| {2}[0-9A-Z]{2}| {3}[0-9A-Z])$`. Of course, trying to make a regex readable is a bit of a fools errand anyway - so maybe code comments would be better!

Comment: @MattBurland I actually like that better.  It helps to not mess up the space count.

Comment: @MattBurland Agreed, spaces are hard to count, so stating the count explicitly is a good idea. Thank you!

Comment: I just noticed the update @dasblinkenlight :)  Thanks for adding the quantifiers!

Answer (score 1):

As per the OP's question, which asks to match alphanumeric characters, the accepted answer will not match lowercase `a-z` unless they specify [`RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx).

so the correct solution should be to pass that option, choose

```
^(|[\w]{4}| {1}[\w]{3}| {2}[\w]{2}| {3}[\w]{1})$
```

or alternatively choose

```
^(|[0-9A-Za-z]{4}| {1}[0-9A-Za-z]{3}| {2}[0-9A-Za-z]{2}| {3}[0-9A-Za-z]{1})$
```

Comment: Thanks for the added solution Pawan.  I actually needed it to only account for uppercase letters actually.  I didn't point it out in the requirements but it was apparent in my regex attempt.  ;)